# Bootstrapping angular RC4 with SystemJS throws Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: angularjs, angular, systemjs

In my current Angular 2 project I've recently started upgrading to the latest release candidate version 2.0.0-RC4. Coming from the beta releases this meant changing all module imports to use the new @angular preface.

After migrating all my code to use the new preface I'm running into trouble using the new systemJS config file. In my config file I map the name 'app' to my compiled typescript files folder, but it seems something is wrong in the config causing the browser to throw the following error:

```
systemjs.config.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The error focuses on the first angle bracket of the html file. As if systemJS tries to run the index.html as the config file.

The map and packages are currently similar to the ones used in the [angular quickstart tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html):

```
//systemjs.config.js
var map = {
    'app': 'app/dist/ts', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
};

var packages = {
    'app': {
        main: 'bootstrap.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: 'index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
};
```

The app is bootstrapped in the index with the following lines:

```
//index.html
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit more to do with RC versions. As a matter of fact, you need to specify explicitly modules like `@angular/core`, ... in the `packages` block of the SystemJS configuration.

For example:

```
var ngPackageNames = [
  'common',
  'compiler',
  'core',
  'forms',
  'http',
  'platform-browser',
  'platform-browser-dynamic',
  'router',
  'router-deprecated',
  'upgrade',
];
// Individual files (~300 requests):
function packIndex(pkgName) {
  packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
// Bundled (~40 requests):
function packUmd(pkgName) {
  packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
// Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
// Add package entries for angular packages
ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
```

Your error is because of 404 not found for a module. If you have a look at  the Network tab of devtools in your browser, you'll see which module is missing...

Comment: I actually used the same systemjs.config.js from the angular tutorial, I just posted the map and packages objects as I thought that's where the problem lies. If I inspect the networks panel the breakpoint lies in the loading of the app in the zone.js file, however that doesn't tell me which of the files it fails to load if that would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After Thierry's response I tried to figure out which files weren't properly loaded, and came to the conclusion that the problem isn't an angular or systemjs problem at all. SystemJS tried to load the index.html because the backend node server supplies the index.html to all requests because angular needs to receive the index at every request. After correctly configuring the server to supply the systemjs.config.js when requested the problem vanished. Thanks for the tips Thierry!

Answer (score 0):

From this code you pasted debugging the issue might not be possible as the file seems correct from now. This error could appear even if any of the module in `systemjs.config.js` is not loaded properly, due to your **file structure**.

I have created a small angular 2 app. You can see the source of it [here](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet) on Github. Please see the `systemjs.config.js` there and the file structure. I hope it might help you resolve the issue as the app is working properly. Please ask in case of some confusion. Thank you